# Avro class cannot be cast to class org.springframework.messaging.Message

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

I am consuming Avro data coming from Debezium

I made the kafka consumer as follows:

1. The Java POJO

   ```
   import lombok.Data;

   @Data
   public class Shop {

    Long shopId;
    Double latitude, longitude;
    String name;
    String phoneNumber;
    String placeId;
    double rating;
    String website;
    int addressId;
    String closingHours;
    String email;
    int maxAttendance;
    String opening_hours;
    String businessHours;
    String closeDay;
    String description;
    boolean open;
    String setWeekendBusinessHours;
    Long userShopId;
   }
   ```
2. Avro Message Format

```
     {
         "type": "record",
         "name": "ShopMessage",
         "namespace": "com.example.kafka.avro",
         "fields": [
         {
          "name": "SHOP_ID",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "long"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "LATITUDE",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "double"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "LONGITUDE",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "double"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "NAME",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "PHONENUMBER",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "PLACEID",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "RATING",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "double"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "WEBSITE",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "ADDRESSID",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "int"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "CLOSINGHOUR",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "EMAIL",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "MAXATTENDANCE",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "int"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "OPENINGHOURS",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "BUSINESSHOURS",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "CLOSEDAY",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "DESCRIPTION",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "ISOPEN",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "boolean"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "WEEKENDBUSINESSHOURS",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "string"
          ],
          "default": null
         },
         {
          "name": "USERSHOPID",
          "type": [
            "null",
            "long"
          ],
          "default": null
         }
        ]
       }
```

3. ShopConsumer

```
@Component
public class ShopConsumer {

    private final ShopMapper shopMapper;
    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ShopConsumer.class);

    public ShopConsumer(ShopMapper shopMapper) {
        this.shopMapper = shopMapper;
    }

    @KafkaListener(
            groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}",
            topics = "${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}"
    )
    public void listen(List<Message<ShopMessage>> messages, Acknowledgment ack){
        log.info("Received batch of messages with size: {}", messages.size());
        List<Shop> shops = messages.stream()
                .peek(this::logMessageReceived)
                .map(message -> shopMapper.toChange(message.getPayload()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //do remove redis cache
        ack.acknowledge();
    }

    private void logMessageReceived(Message<ShopMessage> message) {
        log.info("Received shopId {} with a name of '{} and place id {}', partition={}, offset={}",
                message.getPayload().getSHOPID(),
                message.getPayload().getNAME(),
                message.getPayload().getPLACEID(),
                message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID),
                message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET));
    }
```

4. Consumer Config - ShopConsumerConfig.java

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ShopsConsumerConfig {

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    public ShopsConsumerConfig(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ShopMessage> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ShopMessage> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(false);
        factory.setConcurrency(kafkaProperties.getListener().getConcurrency());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(kafkaProperties.getListener().getAckMode());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, ShopMessage> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroWithSchemaDeserializer.class);

        props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getProperties().get("schema-registry-url"));
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(SpecificAvroWithSchemaDeserializer.AVRO_VALUE_RECORD_TYPE, ShopMessage.class);
        return props;
    }

}
```

5. Schema Deserializer

```
public class SpecificAvroWithSchemaDeserializer extends AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer implements Deserializer<Object> {

    public static final String AVRO_KEY_RECORD_TYPE = "avro.key.record.type";
    public static final String AVRO_VALUE_RECORD_TYPE = "avro.value.record.type";

    private Schema readerSchema;

    public SpecificAvroWithSchemaDeserializer() { }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        this.configure(new KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig(configs));
        readerSchema = getSchema(getRecordClass(configs, isKey));
    }

    private Class<?> getRecordClass(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        String configsKey = isKey ? AVRO_KEY_RECORD_TYPE : AVRO_VALUE_RECORD_TYPE;
        Object configsValue = configs.get(configsKey);

        if (configsValue instanceof Class) {
            return (Class<?>) configsValue;
        } else if (configsValue instanceof String) {
            String recordClassName = (String) configsValue;
            try {
                return Class.forName(recordClassName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unable to find the class '%s'", recordClassName));
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format("A class or a string must be informed into ConsumerConfig properties: '%s' and/or '%s'",
                            AVRO_KEY_RECORD_TYPE, AVRO_VALUE_RECORD_TYPE));
        }
    }

    private Schema getSchema(Class<?> targetType) {
        try {
            Field field = targetType.getDeclaredField("SCHEMA$");
            return (Schema) field.get(null);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format("Unable to get Avro Schema from the class '%s'", targetType.getName()), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(String topic, byte[] bytes) {
        return super.deserialize(bytes, readerSchema);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }


}
```

6. Mapper Class

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ShopMapper {

    default Shop toChange(ShopMessage shopMessage){
        if(shopMessage == null){
            return null;
        }
        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setDescription(shopMessage.getDESCRIPTION().toString());
        shop.setMaxAttendance(shopMessage.getMAXATTENDANCE());
        shop.setSetWeekendBusinessHours(shopMessage.getWEEKENDBUSINESSHOURS().toString());
        shop.setOpen(shopMessage.getISOPEN());
        shop.setWebsite(shopMessage.getWEBSITE().toString());
        shop.setRating(shopMessage.getRATING());
        shop.setLatitude(shopMessage.getLATITUDE());
        shop.setLongitude(shopMessage.getLONGITUDE());
        shop.setCloseDay(shopMessage.getCLOSEDAY().toString());
        shop.setBusinessHours(shopMessage.getBUSINESSHOURS().toString());
        shop.setPhoneNumber(shopMessage.getPHONENUMBER().toString());
        shop.setEmail(shopMessage.getEMAIL().toString());
        shop.setPlaceId(shopMessage.getPLACEID().toString());

        return shop;
    }

}
```

Configuration is present on the `application.properties` file but during message consumption, Spring throws me an error of

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.kafka.avro.ShopMessage cannot be cast to class org.springframework.messaging.Message (com.example.kafka.avro.ShopMessage and org.springframework.messaging.Message are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Could someone give me a correct direction to fix this issue, please? Looks like casting from POJO from Avro is having the issue but I am not able to find the root.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**

After few attempt, it looks that the issue on the above error is due to casting from a single message to list of messages. I changed the listener function as below.

```
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<Integer ,?> messages, Acknowledgment ack){
        //log.info("Received batch of messages with size: {}", messages.size());
        log.info(messages.key());
        log.info(messages.value());
  
        ack.acknowledge();
    }
```

and getting a value from Kafka topic.

```
{"before": {"id": 6, "latitude": 2.921318, "longitude": 101.655938, "name": "XYZ", "phone_number": "+12345678", "place_id": "P007", "rating": 5.0, "type": "Food", "website": "https://xyz.me", "address_id": 5, "closing_hours": null, "email": "info@xyz.me", "max_attendance": 11, "opening_hours": null, "business_hours": "09-18", "close_day": "Saturday", "description": "Some Dummy", "is_open": true, "weekend_business_hours": "08-12", "user_shop_id": 0}, "after": {"id": 6, "latitude": 2.921318, "longitude": 101.655938, "name": "XYZ - edited", "phone_number": "+12345678", "place_id": "P007", "rating": 5.0, "type": "Food 2", "website": "https://xyz.me", "address_id": 5, "closing_hours": null, "email": "info@xyz.me", "max_attendance": 11, "opening_hours": null, "business_hours": "09-18", "close_day": "Saturday", "description": "Some dummy", "is_open": true, "weekend_business_hours": "08-12", "user_shop_id": 0}, "source": {"version": "1.6.0.Final", "connector": "mysql", "name": "bookingdev_sqip_local", "ts_ms": 1629267837000, "snapshot": "false", "db": "booking", "sequence": null, "table": "shop", "server_id": 1, "gtid": null, "file": "mysql-bin.000044", "pos": 26432, "row": 0, "thread": null, "query": null}, "op": "u", "ts_ms": 1629267836453, "transaction": null}
```

apart of that, I also removed the custom deserializer and custom POJO as schema is already installed on the schema registry.

Now the question remains, how do I obtain debezium's schema generated from schema-registry and convert the message to the correct Java POJO to be executed further?

---

**Update 19.08.2021**

After discussion with @OneCricketeer, I made adjustment on the logic for Consumer as below

```
 public void listen(ConsumerRecord<Integer, GenericRecord> messages, Acknowledgment ack) throws JsonProcessingException {
       
        log.info(messages.key());
        log.info(messages.value());

      

        Shop shop = new ObjectMapper().readValue(messages.value().get("after").toString(), Shop.class);
        log.info("NEW VALUE #####-> " + shop.getName());
        
        //other logic here.

        ack.acknowledge();
    }
```

But I got another error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:194) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:112) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1598) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1210) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition bookingdev_sqip_local.booking.shop-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class bookingdev_sqip_local.booking.shop.Key specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.
```

Checked the Schema-Registry Debezium created two subjects - one for key and one for value.

```
["bookingdev_sqip_local.booking.shop-value","bookingdev_sqip_local.booking.shop-key"]
```

Looks like the error due to unable to map the schema for the key.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - tagging as allowed, do you catch something? thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to define your own POJO or deserializer? You can use the schema to generate a class and AFAICT, the existing Confluent KafkaAvroDeserializer does work with specific types. And can you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: Do you really need Message objects? The error is saying it wants to consume `List<ShopMessage>`

Comment: hello @OneCricketeer, apologize for the delayed response, we live in a diff time-zone. I got the idea to put my own POJO coz normally mapping JSON to Java Objects requires underlying POJO. The grey area which I don't really sure is how to consume the JSON created from Debezium CDC and deserialize it. Some reference I have taken from: https://github.com/ivangfr/springboot-kafka-connect-debezium-ksqldb

Comment: May I know what do you mean with *schema to generate a class?* Avro schema you mean? I have the avsc format on no. 2 above.

Comment: From the Debezium docs, you need to put naming (https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/avro.html) hence I made the avro schema above and mapping. 

What is the correct approach to consume Kafka message generated from MySQL CDC using Confluent Kafka Connect? (with or without AVRO)?

Comment: So "Kafka Connect" is Apache product, not from Confluent... If you refer to the Avro Maven plugin documentation, you'll see what I mean. You can also pair that with the Confluent Schema Registry Maven plugin to download any schemas that Debezium will register with it... In any case, like I said, your error seems to say that you shouldn't wrap your data types with Spring Message class (I don't use Spring, so I could be wrong), and you'd get the same error regardless of json or avro

Comment: So basically, debezium schema that I need to use is already installed on the confluent schema registry? @OneCricketeer.

Comment: I am still not clear how CDC will be deserialize into Java objects to consume further? Is it automatically?

Comment: Yes, it's automatic based on the value.deserializer you've specified in the Consumer. If you want to change the objects after consumption, then you're already doing that in your map/collect

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry I don't quite catch you, could you possibly give me an example of code for the consumer? I made an update on the above post. Or if you wish we can continue in chat so I can understand it clearly.

Comment: I'm saying your code is fine, as written. You consume bytes, which are (behind the scenes, automatically) deserialized into ShopMessage objects. Then you're using `List<Shop> shops = messages.stream()...` to convert that data into a list, but you're doing nothing with that list

Comment: thanks, @OneCricketeer I understand your logic here, now the avsc file I made is different from the one debezium stored on schema-registry. Do I need to re-create the avsc file with the values from debezium schema and re-create the class? I made the original avsc file by comparing my MySQL table.

Comment: I'd say using two schema files complicates things. You can always call getter methods to extract subsets of data, as needed, but you don't need a schema file just to create a POJO unless you plan on producing that to a new Avro-serialized topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after struggling with this Spring Boot <-> Kafka Connector <-> Debezium CDC MySQL. I got a working application.

The architecture:

```
MySQL(Producer) <-> Debezium CDC Kafka Connect <-> Kafka <-> SpringBoot (Consumer)
```

I am using Schema-Registry to store the schema configuration.

`ShopConsumerConfig.java`

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ShopsConsumerConfig {

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    public ShopsConsumerConfig(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Shop> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Shop> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(false);
        factory.setConcurrency(kafkaProperties.getListener().getConcurrency());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(kafkaProperties.getListener().getAckMode());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Shop> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);

        props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getProperties().get("schema-registry-url"));
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, false); //this thing is nasty do not turn to true for this!
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.USE_LATEST_VERSION, true);
        return props;
    }

}
```

`Shop.java` or the Java POJO

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Shop {

    Long id;
    Double latitude, longitude;
    String name;
    String phone_number;
    String place_id;
    String type;
    double rating;
    String website;
    int address_id;
    String closing_hours;
    String email;
    int max_attendance;
    String opening_hours;
    String business_hours;
    String close_day;
    String description;
    String is_open;
    String weekend_business_hours;
    Long user_shop_id;
}
```

and finally the consumer `ShopConsumer.java`

```
@Component
public class ShopConsumer {

    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(ShopConsumer.class);

    @KafkaListener(
            groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}",
            topics = "${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}"
    )
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, GenericRecord> messages, Acknowledgment ack) throws JsonProcessingException {

        //debugging purposes only TODO remove me
        log.info(messages.key());
        log.info(messages.value());
        log.info(messages.value().getSchema().getField("after"));

        //convert the message, obtain the "after" section to get the newly updated value and parse it to Java POJO (in this case Shop.java)
        Shop shop = new ObjectMapper().readValue(messages.value().get("after").toString(), Shop.class);

        //debugging purposes only.
        log.info("NEW VALUE #####-> " + shop.getName());

        //other logic goes here...

        ack.acknowledge();
    }

}
```

I hope this helps anyone out there who is struggling to understand how to consume the Debezium message.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because your Kafka listener method should receive `List<ShopMessage>` instead of `List<Message<ShopMessage>>`.

Try to change this line:

```
    public void listen(List<Message<ShopMessage>> messages, Acknowledgment ack){
```

To:

```
    public void listen(List<ShopMessage> messages, Acknowledgment ack){
```

Also `shopMapper.toChange(message.getPayload())` to `shopMapper.toChange(message)`

Comment: thanks @elhussein hashem, now i have updated the question. looks like my confusion is how to consume schema and convert the message to a Java POJO for further consumption. any ideas?

Comment: What if OP wants access to the message headers?